# Passing Objects into Template::Toolkit

Tags: xml, perl, atom-feed, template-toolkit

I'm writing a script to pull my Stackoverflow activity feed into a webpage, it looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Feed;
use Template;

my $stackoverflow_id = 1691146;
my $stackoverflow_url = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/$stackoverflow_id";

my $template = <<'TEMPLATE';
[% FOREACH item = items %]
[% item.title %]
[% END %]
TEMPLATE

my $tt = Template->new( 'STRICT' => 1 )
  or die "Failed to load template: $Template::ERROR\n";

my $feed = XML::Feed->parse(URI->new($stackoverflow_url));

$tt->process( \$template, $feed )
  or die $tt->error();
```

The template should iterate my activity feed (from `XML::Feed->items()`) and print the title of each. When I run this code I get:

```
var.undef error - undefined variable: items
```

To get it to work I had to change the `process` line to:

```
$tt->process( \$template, { 'items' => [ $feed->items ] } )
```

Can anyone explain why `Template::Toolkit` appears unable to use the `XML::Feed->items()` method?

I've had something similar working with `XML::RSS`:

```
my $rss = XML::RSS->new();
$rss->parse($feed);
$tt->process ( \$template, $rss )
    or die $tt->error();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of tweaks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Feed;
use Template;
use Data::Dumper;

my $stackoverflow_id = 1691146;
my $stackoverflow_url = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/$stackoverflow_id";

my $template = <<'TEMPLATE';
[% FOREACH item = feed.items() %]
[% item.title %]
[% END %]
TEMPLATE

my $tt = Template->new( 'STRICT' => 1 )
  or die "Failed to load template: $Template::ERROR\n";

my $feed = XML::Feed->parse(URI->new($stackoverflow_url));



$tt->process( \$template, { feed => $feed } )
  or die $tt->error();
```

The template compiler expects a plain hash ref, the keys and values of which are stored internally. Giving it an `XML::RSS` object works as it has an `items` element. An `XML::Feed` object doesn't have an `items` element as it is just a wrapper for several implementations (including `XML::RSS`). The template wouldn't get an `XML::Feed` object, it'd get a plain hash ref, something like:

```
{ 'rss' => XML::RSS Object }
```

Wrapping your feed in a hash ref makes the compiler retain the `XML::Feed` object, allowing the processing engine to perform the 'magic' required when `feed.items` is found in the template.

Comment: @RobEarl, the template compiler needs a hash ref with a key pointing at the $feed object. From there it has no problem calling the items method.